# Options not working after some other options in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to typeset something by `tcolorbox`. By default, the box should have no background color(by the option `blank`). Then in the Exp 2, a box with background color of red is needed, but the option `colback=red` fails to work. The latter option has not priority over the former one?

Why? And how to make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\test[2][]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[blank,#1]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
% Exp 1.
\test{no backgroud color as expected}
% Exp 2.
\test[colback=red]{backgroud color of red is wanted, but not work}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want the `\test` command to behave exactly? That you want to delete the `blank` whenever the optional argument `#1` is provided?

Comment: I don't want to delete `blank` when using `#1`. I wonder how to make options after `blank` work.

Comment: So what kind of output do you want with `blank,colback=red`? (can you reproduce it manually?)

Comment: With `blank,colback=red`, all the effects by `blank`(no boxrule for example) are kept except that the background color of the box changes to red.

Comment: I guess the option `blank` suppresses `colback` (`standard jigsaw,opacityback=0` seems also to suppress `colback`). So my question is how to remove this kind of suppression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `colback` key only defines a color, but as with `blank` you give the instruction not to draw a background the color is not used. Instead you must change the `interior style`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\test[2][]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[blank,#1]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
% Exp 1.
\test{no background color as expected}
% Exp 2.
\test[interior style={fill=red}]{background color of red is wanted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does that mean if the option `blank` is used, it is impossible to remove its suppresion to related options in  `\begin{tocolorbox}[ ... ]`?

Answer (score 1):

In the doc of tbcolorbox

[image]

With optional blank it works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \test { O{blank} +m}
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[#1]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% Exp 1.
\test{no backgroud color as expected}
% Exp 2.
\test[colback=red]{backgroud color of red is wanted, but not work}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @pascal974. In this post, I just give a MWE to illustrated my desire. In my real code, there are many other default options (all by #1). So the option `blank` is not possible to be deleted in the way you give.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to define two different boxes, a `blank` one and not `blank`, but if you insist in `test` command, you can define two diferent styles and use the convinient in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    blankbox/.style={
        blank, #1},
    redbox/.style={
        colback=red!80, #1}
}

\newcommand\test[2][]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[#1]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
% Exp 1.
\test[blankbox]{no backgroud color as expected}
% Exp 2.
\test[redbox={colframe=blue}]{backgroud color of red is wanted, but not work}
\end{document}
```

[image]